# how can set animation to SearchView EditText

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I want to set animation to SearchView EditText in android-support-v7-appcompat
(appear EditText)

my code is :

```
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

        //searchView.setLayoutTransition(transition);
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);   
            final Animation mLoadAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in);
            mLoadAnimation.setDuration(50000);
            final EditText searchSourceText = (EditText)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
            searchView.setOnClickListener(new SearchView.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    searchSourceText.startAnimation(mLoadAnimation);
                }
            });
```

I want animation run when on Click on SearchView (Appear EditText);

Comment: What's the issue with your code?

Comment: I want animation run when on Click on SearchView (Appear EditText)

Comment: Initialize the animation in the `onClick` method itself. The GC might remove it, because it's not used outside `onCreate`.

Comment: can you send full code for me please?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code is in `onCreate()`.
Simply initialize the animation in the `onClick()` method itself.

```
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView(); 
    searchView.setOnClickListener(new SearchView.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animation mLoadAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in);
            mLoadAnimation.setDuration(50000); //50 seconds
            EditText searchSourceText = (EditText)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
            searchSourceText.startAnimation(mLoadAnimation);
        }
    });
```

No need for finals, do all the logic when you need it.

Comment: Cannot refer to a non-final variable searchView inside an inner class defined in a different method !!!!!!